# How to write an overbar and subscript infinity in the same xlabel on a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, latex

I want the xlabel of my Matlab figure to read v / Uinf, where the v has an overbar, and the inf is a symbol in subscript.

The line:

```
xlabel('$\bar{v}$','interpreter','latex')
```

creates the v overbar, and:

```
xlabel('U_\infty')
```

creates the U subscript infinity, but when I try to put them together, Matlab says 'String must have valid interpreter syntax'. It seems setting the interpreter to latex means the U_\infty command doesn't work any more.

Is there a way of writing U_infty that is compatible with latex or another way of writing the two together?

Thanks in advance,

Holly

Comment: How did you combine them, `xlabel('$\bar{v}/U_\infty$','interpreter','latex')`?

Comment: I was trying a different way but this works better! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In LaTeX, `U_\infty` works only in math mode, so you have to write `$U_\infty$` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly:
xlabel(['$\bar{v}$','/','$U_\infty$'], 'interpreter', 'latex')

Comment: Or, as above, `xlabel(['$\bar{v}/U_\infty$'], 'interpreter', 'latex')`